# Postman Twinfield API request deleted transactions

Tags: soap, postman, twinfield

I'm trying to request the deleted transactions from the twinfield api. As far as I can get from the [documentation](https://accounting.twinfield.com/webservices/documentation/#/ApiReference/Transactions/DeletedTransactions) I'm making a valid request with Postman but everytime I get a return code 500 -> internal server error.
I'm using the following soap request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:twin="http://www.twinfield.com/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <twin:Header>
            <twin:AccessToken>{{Accescode}}</twin:AccessToken>
            <twin:CompanyCode>{{Company}}</twin:CompanyCode>
        </twin:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Query i:type="a:GetDeletedTransactions" xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.DeletedTransactionsService">
            <b:CompanyCode>{{Company}}</b:CompanyCode>
            <b:Daybook>SomeDaybook</b:Daybook>
            <b:DateFrom>2021-04-01</b:DateFrom>
            <b:DateTo>2021-04-02</b:DateTo>
        </Query>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

the headersettings look the following:
[headersettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZD5KB.png)

I've tried it ony the company code as the rest is optional but this gave me the same result.

Any advise on how to get the return with the deleted transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was de XML schema that was missing, the correct XML envelope needs to look like this

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:Authentication xmlns:h="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AccessToken xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.Shared">{{Accescode}}</AccessToken>
            <CompanyCode xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.Shared">{{Company}}</CompanyCode>
        </h:Authentication>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Query i:type="b:GetDeletedTransactions" xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:b="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.DeletedTransactionsService">
            <b:CompanyCode>{{Company}}</b:CompanyCode>
            <b:DateFrom>2022-01-01T00:00:00</b:DateFrom>
            <b:DateTo>2022-12-31T23:59:00</b:DateTo>
            <b:Daybook></b:Daybook>
        </Query>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

your datefrom and dateto values are invalid. Those should not include the date seperators (-).
this should work:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:twin="http://www.twinfield.com/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <twin:Header>
            <twin:AccessToken>{{Accescode}}</twin:AccessToken>
            <twin:CompanyCode>{{Company}}</twin:CompanyCode>
        </twin:Header>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <Query i:type="a:GetDeletedTransactions" xmlns="http://www.twinfield.com/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Twinfield.WebServices.DeletedTransactionsService">
            <b:CompanyCode>{{Company}}</b:CompanyCode>
            <b:Daybook>SomeDaybook</b:Daybook>
            <b:DateFrom>20210401000000</b:DateFrom>
            <b:DateTo>20210402235959</b:DateTo>
        </Query>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it was working with the "-" in the dates. In the end I've had contact with the support and they gave me a different xml envelope. I've posted it as the answer, but thanks anyways!